# How can I find Wronskian determinant with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sympy

I am trying to find these 3 function's Wronskian determinant but the code has  "TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc det ". How can I solve it?

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
e=sp.exp(-3*x) #inputs
f=sp.cos(2*x) 
g=sp.sin(2*x)
buneya=np.array([e,f,g],dtype=object)


a=sp.diff(buneya[0]) #first derivative
b=sp.diff(buneya[1])
c=sp.diff(buneya[2])

k=sp.diff(a)
l=sp.diff(b) #second derivative
m=sp.diff(c)
wronskian=np.array([[e,f,g],[a,b,c],[k,l,m]],dtype=object)
print (np.linalg.det(wronskian) )  #determinant
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\canat\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 20, in <module>
    print (np.linalg.det(wronskian) )

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in det

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 2159, in det
    r = _umath_linalg.det(a, signature=signature)

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc det
```

Comment: Show a traceback please

Comment: @MadPhysicist done

Comment: Also, np.linalg.det operates on concrete numbers, not arrays of symbolic objects. Does sympy have a determinant function?

Comment: I highly recommend formatting the traceback as code. Use triple backticks to avoid having to indent anything.

Comment: I have no idea about sympy det

Comment: That's your best bet unless you can evaluate the elements as concrete numbers for some concrete x

Answer (score 4):

It is that simple:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
e=sp.exp(-3*x) #inputs
f=sp.cos(2*x) 
g=sp.sin(2*x)
buneya=[e,f,g]

a=sp.diff(buneya[0]) #first derivative
b=sp.diff(buneya[1])
c=sp.diff(buneya[2])

k=sp.diff(a)
l=sp.diff(b) #second derivative
m=sp.diff(c)
wronskian=sp.Matrix([[e,f,g],[a,b,c],[k,l,m]]).det()
print(wronskian)
```

returns

```
26*exp(-3*x)*sin(2*x)**2 + 26*exp(-3*x)*cos(2*x)**2
```

see sympy matrices [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html) for further info.

**EDIT #1**
And even simpler!

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.matrices import dense

x = sp.Symbol('x')
e=sp.exp(-3*x) #inputs
f=sp.cos(2*x) 
g=sp.sin(2*x)

wronskian = dense.wronskian([e,f,g],x)
print(wronskian)
```

returns the same

```
26*exp(-3*x)*sin(2*x)**2 + 26*exp(-3*x)*cos(2*x)**2
```

`wronskian` method is also documented in sympy [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.dense.wronskian).